# eBay API - filter items by store/custom categories

Tags: ebay-api

My scenario: I have a client with an eBay store with custom categories. On their website, they would like to list the items they have for sale. They would like this list to be filterable by custom category.

I've been searching for a couple days now, and I'm still a bit unsure about the best way to proceed.

From what I can gather, the only way to get a list of categories defined in a store is through the GetStore call in the Trading API. This seems to be supported, though I need to get a user token from my client's eBay account. I will assume this works.

I do not, however, see any method of filtering items based on custom categories. I've looked through the documentation of both the Trading and Finding APIs, but all I see are filters on pre-defined eBay categories.

Is it possible to filter on custom/store categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through and posting in the eBay forums, I found out that no, it is not possible to filter on custom/store defined categories via the API. The only way to filter on custom/store defined categories is on the eBay hosted store.

This is apparently eBay's way to make the store hosted on their site more feature rich than anything you can do via the API.

Comment: For #Net and php looks more help available

Answer (score 5):

I had a task to link seller products to custom categories and the only way I found is to retrieve a list of custom categories with "GetStore" from Trading API, retrieve all seller items with "findItemsAdvanced" call form Finding API, and loop through all retrieved items and get details with "GetItem" call from Trading API.

After that I could find custom categories under `$xml->Item->Storefront->StoreCategoryID` and `$xml->Item->Storefront->StoreCategory2ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is old, I believe it interesting to give a more recent answer. As stated above, you cannot directly filter items sold by a store using custom store categories (StoreCategoryID). The easiest way to work around this is using the GetSellerList API using a coarse granularity level, which allows you to get the storeCategoryID of each Item on sale within a starting time range or an end time range. You can then filter the items yourself. Here's a link to a forum answer: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1178

Answer (score 0):

Yes no way to get items by Custom categories.

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like either [getCategoryInfo](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetCategoryInfo.html) or [GetCategories](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetCategories.htm) might help you.